# Problems with pygame collisions

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to do horizontal and vertical collisions, and I'm having problems with horizontal. I've used collisioncheck as a method to verify how many tiles a player is touching, as that's the only difference I could think of for horizontal and vertical. But, my player never touches 2 tiles as the vertical collisions for some reason always comes first and instead of colliding with 2 tiles my player simply gets sent up.

```py
collisioncheck=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.player,self.tiles,False,False)
for tile in self.tiles.sprites():
    if player.rect.colliderect(tile.rect):
        if player.direction.y>0:
            player.rect.bottom=tile.rect.top
            player.direction.y=0
        elif player.direction.y<0:
            player.rect.top=tile.rect.bottom
            player.direction.y=0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You must handle horizontal and vertical movements and collisions separately:

- Move the player in x-direction
- Detect the collisions and limit the movement of the player in X-direction
- Move the player in y-direction
- Detect the collisions and limit the movement of the player in y-direction

You can try to separate only the collision detection and the limitation of the players position depending on the movement axis and not the movement itself, however this may not completely solve your problem. It will be a problem if you always fall down slightly, even if you are standing on a tile, so the horizontal collision detection will always detect a collision with the tiles you are standing on.

Your code should look something like this:

```py
# do the horizontal movement here, something like:
# player.rect.x += player.direction.x

collide_x = False
collisioncheck=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.player,self.tiles,False,False)
for tile in self.tiles.sprites():
    if player.rect.colliderect(tile.rect):
        if player.direction.x > 0:
            player.rect.right = tile.rect.left
            collide_x = True
        elif player.direction.x < 0:
            player.rect.left = tile.rect.right
            collide_x = True
if collide_x:
    player.direction.x = 0

# do the vertical movement here, something like:
# player.rect.y += player.direction.y

collide_y = False
collisioncheck=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.player,self.tiles,False,False)
for tile in self.tiles.sprites():
    if player.rect.colliderect(tile.rect):
        if player.direction.y > 0:
            player.rect.bottom = tile.rect.top
            collide_y = True
        elif player.direction.y <= 0:
            player.rect.top = tile.rect.bottom
            collide_y = True
if collide_y:
   player.direction.y = 0
```